# C# datetime scope

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Assuming I can not change service that returns data, I am left with

```
var date = "20140231";
var scope = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Clearly "20140231" is lazy way of saying **end of February**. What is the cleanest way to get last date of February with input of "20140231"?

There is 1 constraint - this should work with .net 2.0.

Comment: What about leap years though?

Comment: What about "20140230"?

Comment: Well, this example is not a random pick. I still want last date of the month for inputs 29, 30, 31.

Comment: If date is of fixed 8 char data, Why don't you separate the year, month and date yourself and calculate what you want. . ..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
string date = "20140231";
DateTime result;
int year = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(0, 4));
int month = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(4, 2));
int day = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(6, 2));

result = new DateTime(year, month, Math.Min(DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month), day));
```

Answer (score 5):

[February](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February) can have *only* `28` or `29` days depends on current year is a [leap year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) or not.

It can't have `30` or `31` days in any year. That's why you can't parse your `20140231` string successfully.

You can clearly get the last day of February like;

```
DateTime lastDayOfFebruary = (new DateTime(2014, 2, 1)).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

If your service *always* get year as a first 4 character, you can use [`.Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) to get year and pass [`DateTime` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a year.

```
var date = "20140231";
string year = date.Substring(0, 4);
DateTime lastDayOfFebruary = (new DateTime(int.Parse(year), 2, 1)).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: How does this convert the date provided from the service?

Comment: So **new DateTime(int.Parse(date.Substring(1,4)), int.Parse(date.Substring(5,6)), int.Parse(date.Substring(7,8)))**, would return March 3 in this case? I could do new **DateTime(int.Parse(date.Substring(1,4)), int.Parse(date.Substring(5,6)), 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)** and take min, but thats not very clean.

Comment: @PatrickHofman OP _can't_ parse `20140231` string in Gregorian calender because there is no such a date. If the string that service return always have year as a first 4 character, he can pass this value in a `DateTime` constructor.

Comment: @SonerGönül: I guess that was the point. The date returned from the service is invalid.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Exactly. We _can't_ parse a string that doesn't exist as a `DateTime` :)

Comment: @Margus Your example string is not a valid `DateTime` as I said, but for other examples (which are they valid datetimes); `20140101`, , `20140131`, `20140201`, you are good to choose `yyyyMMdd` format to parse them. Dividing your string for parsing is _generally_ a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `while`, cut the date in pieces, and keep subtracting one from the day part until it is a valid date. This should really be fixed on the entry side though.

Try this:

```
var date = "20140231";
DateTime scope;
bool dateValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out scope);

while (!dateValid)
{
    string yearMonth = date.Substring(0, 4);
    int day = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(6, 2));

    if (day > 1)
    {
        day--;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }

    date = yearMonth + day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');

    dateValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out scope);
}
```